# How to have form submission as an event for NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, event-handling, listener

I know normally a form submission will be handled via a dedicated endpoint, as in "action="/foo/bar"".
Is it possible to treat the form submission as an event in a NodeJS application, similar to waiting for a response from an external service? Is it possible to render the page, and register a callback of some sort that will be triggered when the user submits?

What are the pros and cons of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a use of callback function .. here is a pseudocode that u can make use of

```
    app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('form-to-be-submitted', function(req, res){
        .....
        ......


        res.redirect('/foo/bar');
        ......
        ......
        var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body))
        // use your input value as you desired

    })
```

}

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot treat a form submission as an event in your node.js app.  This is because the form and the app are in separate environments.  The form exists on the client side whilst the app runs on the server side.

If you want to avoid using the form action method, you can "submit" the form via ajax to an API in the app.